# Adsense Host Api start associated Session redirect to main page

Tags: php, google-app-engine, adsense-api

I try to make authorization with adsesnse Host Api and I have working code to generate url to authorization which redirect to login/register in adsense but after login/register i am redirecting to main page of my site I want to redirect to custom address to make verify. How can I set redirect url after register process?

I use Google Host api library for google Adsense Host Api

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a client_secrets.json file the redirectUrl is probably set there. It can also be set directly in the code.

Be sure you change/add the new redirect location using [console.developers.google.com](http://console.developers.google.com) before you change it locally - it can take a while (tens of minutes) for changes here to take effect.

Edit: OK - wrong redirect sorry.  For that one you will need to contact Adsense and ask them to update your landing page url.

Comment: i'm setting up redirect url and i'am redirecting to adsense confirmation then back to my site and make authorization and redirecting me to login/register with adsense and after this i am redirecting to main page of my site.